Enums in JNI GetMethodID signature parameter list
So, this is an edge case that no amount of Googling seems to unearth.
I have an enum in Kotlin;
package myapp
public enum State {
    STATE_SUCCEEDED,
    STATE_FROZEN,
    STATE_WAITING,
    STATE_IN_PROGRESS,
    STATE_FAILED
}

I then have an object that contains this enum as a value in a member variable
package myapp
class AppState (
    val state: State
)

Then, in C, I want to create an instance of AppState
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, AppState_ClassPath);
if (cls == NULL) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "DEBUG", "AppState class is null");
}
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "(Lmyapp/State;)V");
return (*env)->NewObject(
    env, 
    cls, 
    mid, 
    enumState
);

Now, when the C code is called from Kotlin, I get the error
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewStringUTF called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lmyapp/AppState;.<init>(Lmyapp/State;)V"

I understand why I get this error, since Enums have no public constructor, but not sure of the workaround.  How should this enum be added to the signature?
Many thanks!
EDIT: (output from javap)
public final class myapp.AppState {
  public myapp.AppState(myapp.State);
    descriptor: (Lmyapp/State;)V

  public final myapp.State getState();
    descriptor: ()Lmyapp/State;
}

EDIT 2: (enum conversion function)
jobject
getState(JNIEnv* env, enum State state) {
    char path[64];
    char* stateName;

    switch(state) {
        case STATE_SUCCEEDED:
            stateName = "STATE_SUCCEEDED";
            break;
        case STATE_FROZEN:
            stateName = "STATE_FROZEN";
            break;
        case STATE_WAITING:
            stateName = "STATE_WAITING";
            break;
        case STATE_IN_PROGRESS:
            stateName = "STATE_IN_PROGRESS";
            break;
        default:
            stateName = "STATE_FAILED";
    };

    snprintf(path, sizeof(path) - 1,"[L%s;", State_ClassPath);
    jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, State_ClassPath);
    jfieldID fid = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env, cls , stateName, path);
    jobject stateObj = (*env)->GetStaticObjectField(env, cls, fid);
    return stateObj;
}


You don't create instances of enum values. They are static fields of the enum class. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51729992/create-a-java-enum-from-the-jni/

Sure, I get that, but how then does one pass an enum value via a method call?

What is enumState here? a jobject or an integer?

Cannot reproduce on my system. That constructor is just there .. Can you inspect the class file for AppState with javap -s?

"but how then does one pass an enum value via a method call?" I show that in the answer that I linked to (the last row with the NewObject call).

It's Kotllin, so javap -s won't work

@Botje I acquire a value from the Enum object in C, so it's a jobject.

I did just that on my system. Compiled with kotlinc and ran javap -s myapp/AppState.class.

Okay, i'm a C/C++ engineer, so Kotlin is still new to me.  I managed to output from javap. I've added it to the main post for clarity.

Okay, I'm a bit further. The GetMethodID no longer errors, but when getting the state to pass to it, I get JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetStaticObjectField called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "[Lmyapp/State;" field "STATE_IN_PROGRESS" in class "Lmyapp/State;" or its superclasses. Function for acquiring the enum is added to the main question.

[ in a signature implies a Java array. Remove that character.

And don't fail to check all your JNI calls for errors and pending exceptions.

The answer turned out to be an erroneous [ in the code.  Using javap -s and copying / pasting from the output is the safest way to avoid this issue.
